# How do I get the status of another Activity's Switch?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a XML file called activity_settings.xml and I have a `Switch` in it. And I have Java class file named Start.java (which is not related to activity_settings.xml).

I wanted to use the id of the `Switch` in Start.java to know whether the Switch is on/off.

Is it possible to use another layout elements in another java class files?

Here is my code for Start.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
      aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus); //set the switch to ON aSwitch.setChecked(true); 
      //attach a listener to check for changes in state 
      aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {
                  Toast.makeText(Start.this, "ONNNNNN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(Start.this, "OFFFFFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          }
      });
  }
```

My activity.xml:

```
<Switch android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Switch " />
```

Comment: where is `activity.xml` ?

Comment: Please use better names for naming your `Activity`s and `Fragment`s. The name **Start.java** seems like a POJO but I guess it's an `Activity` by looking at the code more closely. Please check [this link](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/project_and_code_guidelines.md) out which lists down naming conventions.

Comment: Are you opening `Start` Activity from `SettingsActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

use it in your switch class:

```
String switchON;


protected void onCreate(Bundle   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

      aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchStatus); 
    //set the switch to ON aSwitch.setChecked(true); 
      //attach a listener to check for changes in state 

aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked) {

        switchON = "yes";
                  Toast.makeText(Start.this, "ONNNNNN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } else {

        switchON = "no";
                  Toast.makeText(Start.this, "OFFFFFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
          }
      });
  }


//Use Intent with your next activity button click
String switchON;
Intent intent = new Intent(SwitchActivity.this, OtherActivity.class){
intent.putExtra("switch_on", switchON);
StartActivity(intent);
}


//use it in your OtherActivity

Intent intent = getIntent();
String switchON = intent.getStringExtra("switch_on");
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access `View`s of another Activity. Because, it is against how the framework is designed. Moreover, you can never be sure that the other Activity hasn't been destroyed yet (due to low memory, etc).

So, if you're opening your `Start` Activity from `SettingsActivity`, you should do like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Start.class);
intent.putExtra("switchOn", yourSwitch.isChecked());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your `Start` Activity's `onCreate()`, you can check if your `SetingsActivity`'s Switch was checked or not:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean switchChecked = intent.getBooleanExtra("switchOn");
```

Comment: I dont  want to start new activity how can i do this???? I just want to share whether switch is on/off

Comment: @PrakashElugoti if the SettingsActivity is not created, how can its Switch be created and accessible? Please explain about what actually you want to do. Like what is your flow?